# Аналог __non_webpack_require__ для Vue Cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue-cli, require

работаю над веб приложением основанным на Vue Cli и интересует вопрос:

Мне необходимо при запуске подгружать некоторые метаданные и при работе с webpack я использовал `__non_webpack_require__`, но Vue Cli не знает такого метода. Есть ли аналог который не запаковывает указанный модуль и преобразовывает его в `require(path)`?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69900231/analog-of-non-webpack-require-for-vue-cli